# Realm add item to RealmList that is added to RealmObject

Tags: android, list, realm

I need to solve putting data to a realm database like this:

I have an object called obtained_code;
I have a realmList of Obtained codes in an object called Offer;
I download obtained codes separately, and by their offer id assign them to the lists of each object. The problem is that I can't add them because when I check the size, it's always 0.

Here is the code:

```
ObtainedCodes codes = response.body();
                for (ObtainedCode c : codes.getObtainedCodes()) {
                    Offer offer = RealmController.with(SplashActivity.this).getOffer(c.getOffer_id());
                    if (offer != null) {
                        Log.d("Size", "Offer not null");
                        realm1.beginTransaction();
                        RealmList<ObtainedCode> list = offer.getObtained_codes();
                        if (!list) { // if the 'list' is managed, all items in it is also managed
                            RealmList<ObtainedCode> managedImageList = new RealmList<>();
                            for (ObtainedCode item : list) {
                                if (item) {
                                    managedImageList.add(item);
                                } else {
                                    managedImageList.add(realm1.copyToRealm(item));
                                }
                            }
                            list = managedImageList;
                        }

                        offer.setObtained_codes(obtainedCodes);
                        Log.d("Size", String.valueOf(offer.getObtained_codes().size()));
                        realm1.copyToRealmOrUpdate(offer);
                        realm1.commitTransaction();
                    }
                    offer = RealmController.with(SplashActivity.this).getOffer(c.getOffer_id());
                    Log.d("Size", String.valueOf(offer.getObtained_codes().size()));
                }
```

Comment: What's the line before `ObtainedCodes codes = response.body();`?

Comment: ....oh god. `RealmController`? Is this based on Ravi Tamada's monstrousity again?

Comment: There is none. The response is from the Retrofit call.

Comment: Well I just followed some tutorials and the app seems kinda working so what's the problem ?

Comment: Exactly, but if this is the response of an `enqueue()`'s `onSuccess()` callback, then you're writing into the Realm on the UI thread, which is bad. As for `I just followed some tutorials so what's the problem`, I made [**this github repository and Realm sample code**](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example) specifically because of just how bad that tutorial is.

Comment: Oh. So, what is the proper way of doing it and also how can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) the Ravi Tamada tutorial on InfoHive is a terrible mess, please refer to [**my remake of that example instead**](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example).

If you managed to start using 0.82.1 because Ravi Tamada claimed that a 4 years old version is "stable", well I know that it's not. Use 1.2.0 instead (or the latest version which is 3.4.1)

And if you see a `RealmController.with()`, run, because it ignores thread-confinement. The moment you try to access it from a background thread, it'll crash.

On background threads, you'd need to do

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
       repository.whatever(realm); // pass Realm instance to database methods
    } // auto-close
    // end of thread
}
```

2.) you are executing writes on the UI thread, that is bad, from UI thread you should use `realm.executeTransactionAsync()`, but in *your* case you should actually execute the Retrofit call on a background thread using `Ęxecutors.newSingleThreadedPool()` and call it with `call.execute()` instead of `call.enqueue()`.

3.) You should write to Realm on the background thread, and on the UI thread you should use RealmChangeListener to listen to writes.

4.) your code doesn't work because you're setting an unmanaged list to a managed RealmObject.

You should modify the existing RealmList inside the RealmObject, and add only managed objects to it.

---

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); // field variable
// ...

void someMethod() {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Response<ObtainedCodes> response = retrofitService.getObtainedCodes().execute(); // run on current thread
            ObtainedCodes codes = response.body();
            if(codes == null) return;
            try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                r.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        for(ObtainedCode obtainedCode : codes.getObtainedCodes()) {
                            Offer offer = realmRepository.getOffer(realm, obtainedCode.getOfferId());
                            if(offer == null) {
                                offer = realm.createObject(Offer.class, obtainedCode.getOfferId());
                                // map properties to offer if possible
                            }
                            RealmList<ObtainedCode> offerCodes = offer.getObtainedCodes();
                            ObtainedCode managedObtainedCode = realm.where(ObtainedCode.class).equalTo("obtainedCodeId", obtainedCode.getId()).findFirst();
                            if(managedObtainedCode == null) {
                                managedObtainedCode = realm.createObject(ObtainedCode.class, obtainedCode.getId());
                                // map properties from obtained code to managed obtained code
                            }
                            if(!offerCodes.contains(managedObtainedCode)) {
                                offerCodes.add(managedObtainedCode);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ooookay, thanks. I will try to implement your suggestions tomorrow. Could you please also write some example that solves my problem please ?

Comment: I added some sample code, I cannot guarantee that it works out of the box because I do not know your schema.

Comment: Actually I am using that Call<Object> and .enqueue(Callback) style. That means I have to rewrite like 25% of my code. Okay let's ser if it will actually work

Comment: And because you're using `enqueue`, you end up on the UI thread even though you should be writing to Realm on the background thread. And you should be listening for the results of the write using `RealmChangeListener`. As I said, the tutorial you were following is super-duper bad :p

Comment: Well, I implemented your code. And on this activity, everything works fine. But when I go to the next one, the obtainedCodes list size is still 0. Why ?

Comment: I don't see how you are obtaining it in the other activity, so I can't possibly know. Queries returned by Realm point to the same query results on the same thread, as long as they are managed (which means they were queried from Realm)

Comment: Well the thing is I download codes in SplashActivity then I query offer in MainActivity which produces expected results with codes. But when I launch next Activity or query the same thing from fragment no obtained codes. By the way I am using Realm.getDefaultInstance everywhere because couldn't get your RealmManager class to work

Comment: I found what was causing the problem, in my fragment I was refreshing the data once more and overwriting the obtained codes data. Therefore I was receiving size 0 (Facepalm)